# How can we connect mysql trigger with Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, triggers

I'm working on a ROR 3 app which uses mysql as the database. Now I want a trigger every time `col1` of `table1` is updated. But I also want the values of both `col1` and `col2` of that row in my rails controllers after the trigger is completed *( so as to update an dynamic progress bar )* ... What approach can I follow for this??

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) to define a trigger on your table.

A trigger will block the trigggering operation until the trigger completes. There is nothing else to do, just wait until your main query ends.

A trigger has no return value. When your update completes (which means your trigger completed too), issue a separate `SELECT` statement.

Comment: How can i know in my rails controller that the trigger is completed??

Comment: I ended up using unobstrusive javascript for polling database.. which btw works fine :)