# Rails 3 active record observer not working when updating through MySQL command line/workbench

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, observers

I'm working on ROR 3 app . I have added the following observer but I dont see any output as expected in the console or log file ( i have tried in both development and production modes)

**cmd :** `rails g observer auditor`

**models:**

```
class AuditorObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :excel_file

  def after_update(excel_file)
    excel_file.logger.info('New contact added!')
    AuditTrail.new(execl_file, "UPDATED")
    puts "*******************"
    logger.info "********************************************"
  end
end
```

**application.rb:**

```
config.active_record.observers = :auditor_observer
```

What am I missing in here? When I change the database (thru Mysql workbench/command line) I don't see any of the above lines getting executed.. neither `after_update`/`after_save`. But after_save works if I'm executing a query thru the app itself and do `@excel.save`

How else are we supposed to update data in DB so that we see the observer working????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bypass activerecord by modifying the database directly, you naturally bypass all of the activerecord callbacks.

So the answer is to update the data through the application, or to use database triggers instead.

Comment: thank u !! I thought so I was missing something.. Even triggers was my first choice..  But How can I update any variable in my ruby app through mysql triggers??? If u have any idea or links related please tell

Comment: There's certainly no convenient way, unless you set them in and read them from the database. The basic problem here is that you're subverting the application code by bypassing it. It's not a completely impossible problem to solve but your application cannot rely on any data caching, and can't make any assumptions about the state of the data without reading it.

Comment: actually.. our web app has an underlying s/w which ll update  some values in our db. I have to read those values and move a progress bar. Hence that particular data updation will happen by an external source and not my application code :(

Comment: I had asked the question on triggers here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655144/how-can-we-connect-mysql-trigger-with-ruby-on-rails-3) Problem is triggers dont have return values!